# Chromium max number of concurrent HTTP connections

Tags: http, google-chrome, browser, chromium

Could someone point me to the maximum number of concurrent HTTP connections in chromium by default. In case I need to change the value is there a flag which enables that. If not, could you point me to the location in the chromium source where this can be achieved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the 'MaxConnectionsPerProxy' policy template at http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates.[1][2]  It doesn't look like Chrome or Chromium will support configuring the maximum number of concurrent HTTP connections like Firefox does in about:config.[3]

References:

1. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=63658
2. http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates
3. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=87381